# mysql copy schema without data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

using phpmyadmin and mysql i am trying to run the following query without success

```
create TABLE 'amazonUK-crawler' like 'amazonDE-crawler';
```

2 errors were found during analysis.

An opening bracket was expected. (near "like" at position 32)
At least one column definition was expected. (near " " at position 31)

Comment: Those look like single quotes rather than backticks.

Comment: thanks!!! solved it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
CREATE TABLE `amazonUK-crawler` SELECT * FROM `amazonDE-crawler` LIMIT 0
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `amazonUK-crawler` SELECT * FROM `amazonDE-crawler` WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: 2 errors were found during analysis.

An opening bracket was expected. (near "SELECT" at position 32)
At least one column definition was expected. (near " " at position 31)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:

```
CREATE TABLE 'amazonUK-crawler' AS SELECT * FROM  'amazonDE-crawler';
```

Comment: Original question is *mysql copy schema **without data***

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE `amazonUK-crawler` AS SELECT * FROM `amazonDE-crawler`;
```

Comment: Original question is *mysql copy schema **without data***